# Get java.nio.file.Path object from java.io.File

Tags: java, file, path, java-6

Is it possible to get a Path object from a `java.io.File`?

I know you can convert a path to a file using `toFile()` method, but I couldn't find the opposite conversion. Is there a way to do this in Java 6 or lower?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Yes, you can get it from the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object by using [`File.toPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath()). Keep in mind that this is only for Java 7+. Java versions 6 and below do not have it.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in Java 6 or lower?

Comment: `Path` was introduced in Java 7, so unfortunately there is no way to do this in Java 6 and below.

Answer (score 34):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html):

> Paths associated with the default `provider` are generally interoperable
>   with the `java.io.File` class. Paths created by other providers are
>   unlikely to be interoperable with the abstract path names represented
>   by `java.io.File`. **The `toPath` method may be used to obtain a Path from
>   the abstract path name represented by a java.io.File object.** The
>   resulting Path can be used to operate on the same file as the
>   `java.io.File` object. **In addition, the `toFile` method is useful to
>   construct a `File` from the `String` representation of a `Path`.**

(emphasis mine)

So, for [`toFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile%28%29):

> Returns a `File` object representing this path.

And [`toPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath%28%29):

> Returns a `java.nio.file.Path` object constructed from the this abstract path.

Answer (score 22):

You likely want [`File.toPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath%28%29).

Answer (score 11):

As many have suggested, JRE v1.7 and above has File.toPath();

```
File yourFile = ...;
Path yourPath = yourFile.toPath();
```

On Oracle's [jdk 1.7 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath%28%29) which is also mentioned in other posts above, the following equivalent code is described in the description for toPath() method, which may work for JRE v1.6;

```
File yourFile = ...;
Path yourPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(yourFile.getPath());
```