# Java how to convert List of File objects to List of Path objects?

Tags: java, collections, fileutils

I am building a library for which the user already has code that processes an array of Paths.
I have this:

```
Collection<File> filesT = FileUtils.listFiles(
            new File(dir), new RegexFileFilter(".txt$"), 
            DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
          );
```

I use the List of File object throughout but needed a way to convert filesT to *List<Path>*.
Is there a quick way, maybe lambda to quickly convert one list to the other?

Comment: And how did you mean to create a Path object from a File object?

Comment: To be clear, is the conversion from `java.io.File` to `java.nio.file.Path`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Get java.nio.file.Path object from java.io.File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15512200)

Comment: Why don’t you use `Path` in the first place? Getting a filtered list, including pattern matching, is already provided by the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Collection<File>`, you can convert it to `List<Path>` or to `Path[]` using `File::toPath` method reference:

```java
public List<Path> filesToPathList(Collection<File> files) {
    return files.stream().map(File::toPath).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public Path[] filesToPathArray(Collection<File> files) {
    return files.stream().map(File::toPath).toArray(Path[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Sorry late response but this is how I did what I needed to do. I actually used Jim Newpower's Set<Path> type from above. So technically you both have the answer. Thank guys.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex Rudenko's answer, however the toArray() would require a cast.  I present an alternative (how I would implement, returning immutable collections):

```
Set<Path> mapFilesToPaths(Collection<File> files) {
    return files.stream().map(File::toPath).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
}
```